# OnTouchListener on Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, overlay, ontouchlistener

Currently I have an OnTouchListener on a button, and it works properly. The code is as follows:

```
    Button button1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btOk1);
    button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //do some stuff here
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I wish to have an OnTouchListener on my entire Activity instead, so that I do some stuff whenever the user taps on any area of my Activity. My activity's root layout is a TableLayout. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Edit:

I managed to do it by naming my root layout and setting an onTouchListener to use as follows:

```
    View view = findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouch");
            if ((event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) != 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Obscured");
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Alert!")
                        .setMessage("Overlay detected!")
                        .setNeutralButton("Dismiss", null)
                        .show();
                }
                // Return true to prevent the button from processing the touch.
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Not obscured");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I'm now getting touch events whenever I click almost anywhere on the layout. I'm also able to detect overlays that pass touch events to my Activity by comparing the MotionEvent's flag with FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED, but only if the area that was touched is actually obscured. Also, the onTouchListener doesn't seem to be called on touches on UI elements such as Buttons and EditText, but only on blank space.

Is there any way to detect if any part of my Activity is obscured, and is there any way of having a single onTouchListener() for the entire Activity, rather than having separate ones for each UI element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply OnTouchListener to the root layout of your activty. that will sure the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but I had to put an id to the root layout. Another question - is there any way of finding out if the Activity is obscured by any other UI element, e.g. a Toast notification or System Alert? I tried testing for event.getFlags() with MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED, but this seems to only work for areas of the screen where it's obscured, and not other areas that are not obscured.

Comment: I've modified the original post.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know that the touch event occurred, i.e. without information on the touched view, you can override Activity's dispatchTouchEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Relative layout with width and height "fill_parent". 
Then in activity create an onTouchListener for Relative Layout.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout  =(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //do some stuff here
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setOnClickListener(this);
```

It may not work for activities, however it does work for classes that extend SurfaceView